# How to print an array value by value in a loop in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

So my shell script look something like this:

```
VAR=$(shuf -i 1-10 -n 3)
N=1
while [$N le 3 ]; do
    NUM=$VAR | awk '{print$`echo $N`}'
    #some commands that uses $NUM
    N=$(($N+1))
done
```

But I think `awk` does not work here, since

```
echo $VAR | awk '{print$`echo $N`}'
```

gives me

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print$`echo $N`}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ invalid char '`' in expression
awk: cmd. line:1: {print$`echo $N`}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
```

So I tried the following command

```
 echo $VAR | awk '{print$$(echo $N)}'
```

This time I always see all three values, regardless of what `$N` was

Are there other commands I could try?

Comment: If you could let us know your sample Input_file and expected sample output with your requirement, we could help you more on it.

Comment: Not marking it a dupe (for bash array printing), only because it needs some more explanation on shell internals usage.

Answer (score 3):

#### Multiple syntax issues and anti-patterns in use! Do check your script in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for trivial syntax issues.

1. Variables in shell are *not* meant to store multi-line items. Use an array and loop over it.
2. The `bash` constructs are space-sensitive, a simple missed space in `[$N le 3 ]` needs to be written as `[ $N le 3 ]`
3. The syntax for running commands and storing output in a variable is just wrong. The actual command substitution syntax is to use `var=$(..)`, where the `$(..)` contains the commands to be run.
4. You can't run command-substitution (back-ticks or `$(..))` inside `awk`. Remember `awk` is *not* shell. You don't need to use `awk` or any third party tool for iterating over an array, just use the shell internals.

Since `shuf` prints output in new line. Use a tool `mapfile`/`readarray` to store items safely into the array, i.e.

```
mapfile -t randomElements < <(shuf -i 1-10 -n 3)
```

The `<()` is a special construct in `bash` called process substitution which the output of a process (`shuf` in your case) appear as a temporary file to read from.

We now use a loop to iterate over the elements,

```
for ((i=0; i<"${#randomElements[@]}"; i++)); do 
    printf '%s\n' "${randomElements[i]}"
done
```

If by chance `mapfile`/`readarray` which should be available in `bash` versions 4.3 and later is not present, use the `read` command

```
while IFS= read -r line; do arr+=("$line"); done < <(shuf -i 1-10 -n 3)
```

and use the printing logic as usual.

Comment: Or, if index reference is not needed along with the elements, a simple `for i in "${randomElements[@]}"; do ...` works fine as well. (quote `"${randomElements[@]}"` to prevent word splitting)